# ¿Cómo insertar un nuevo registro a una tabla con disparadores?

Tags: sql, oracle-11g, trigger

Tengo un problema tengo que crear un trigger en oracle PL/SQL a nivel fila que cuando se inserte un nuevo registro en la tabla sin indroducir el **id(COD asi se llama el campo)** se tome un id(COD) maximo de los registros que ya existian y en automatico colo que la insertación.

**Mi tablas y registros son así:**

```
 create table personas1(
cod number,
nombre varchar2(30),
edad number (3)
 );
create table personas2(
cod number,
nombre varchar2(30),
edad number (3)
 );
 insert into personas1 values('11','maria',25);
insert into personas1 values('12','pepe',40);
insert into personas1 values('13','pepe',45);
insert into personas1 values('14','luisa',48);
insert into personas1 values('15','pepe',22);

insert into personas2 values('11','maria',25);
insert into personas2 values('12','pepe',40);
insert into personas2 values('13','pepe',45);
insert into personas2 values('14','luisa',48);
insert into personas2 values('15','pepe',22);
```

Comment: La lógica que pides es un tanto problemática. 1) Creo que Oracle no permite consultar la misma tabla que esté ejecutando el disparador. 2) El rendimiento del insert comenzaría a depender de la cantidad de registros en la tabla. 3) Si mas de un insert ejecuta al mismo tiempo, puede que ambos calculen el mismo max y traten de insertar el mismo valor causando error en uno de los inserts.  Por todas estas razones, es mas conveniente usar un `SEQUENCE` para generar los valores de tu columna.

Comment: En cuanto al primer punto que mencioné arriba, técnicamente, es posible que Oracle permita este tipo de disparador si se trata de un insert trigger. Estoy casi seguro que con update trigger recibirías un error del estilo *table is mutating*. De todas formas, por las 2 otras razones que mencioné, sigo recomendándote el uso de un `SEQUENCE`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que entiendo es que quieres hacer un auto-incremento basado en el máximo valor de la columna COD de una tabla, bueno entiendo que te refieres a una sola tabla.

La forma que tengo de hacer esto en PL/SQL involucra a dos triggers uno a nivel de tabla y el otro a nivel de fila. El primero lo uso para obtener el mayor valor de la fila incrementado en 1, el otro trigger es para actualizar el COD en la fila que se está introduciendo, también hay que utilizar una variable para que el primer trigger guarde el valor de COD incrementado y el segundo trigger lo pueda obtener y asignarlo a la columna COD, para esto se crea un PACKAGE con la declaración de una variable, dentro del PACKAGE también va un procedure para asignar el valor y una función para obtenerlo. Todo esto es porque en un trigger de fila no se puede consultar la misma tabla que estás actualizando.

Aquí va mi propuesta de solución.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Dat AS 

  COD PERSONAS1.COD%TYPE ;

  PROCEDURE SET_COD(vCOD IN PERSONAS1.COD%TYPE) ;

  FUNCTION GET_COD RETURN PERSONAS1.COD%TYPE ;

END Dat;
```

/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Dat AS

  PROCEDURE SET_COD(vCOD IN PERSONAS1.COD%TYPE) IS

  BEGIN

    COD := vCOD ;

  END ;

  FUNCTION GET_COD RETURN PERSONAS1.COD%TYPE IS

  BEGIN

    RETURN COD ;

  END ;

END Dat;
```

/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACT_PERSONAS1_STATEMENT

BEFORE INSERT

ON PERSONAS1

DECLARE

  vCod PERSONAS1.COD%TYPE ;

BEGIN

  SELECT MAX(COD) INTO vCOD FROM PERSONAS1 ;

  DAT.SET_COD(vCod+1) ;

END ACT_PERSONAS1_STATEMENT;
```

/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACT_PERSONAS1

BEFORE INSERT

ON PERSONAS1

REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  SELECT DAT.GET_COD INTO :NEW.COD FROM DUAL ;

END ACT_PERSONAS1;
```

/